# Extract logs between time frame with non specific time stamp using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to fetch log between two time stamps but i do not have specific time stamps with me. I can use the command sed for fetching if I have specific time stamp in log using the following command

```
 sed -rne '/$StartTime/,/$EndTime/'p <filename>
```

My query is that since the specific **StartTime** and **EndTime** which I'm fetching from my DB might not be present in the log file, I will have to fetch the log between times near to the **StartTime** and **EndTime** that I provide using **>= and <= signs**. I tried the following command but it does not work.

```
awk '$0>=st && $0<=et' st=$StartTime et=$EndTime <filename>
```

Sample input and output

**Input**

**Time retrieved from DB**

StartTime - 2017-11-02 10:20:00

EndTime - 2017-11-02 11:20:00

**The time present in log**

T1 - 2017-11-02 10:17:44

T2 - 2017-11-02 11:19:32

**Output:** Entire Log text between T1 & T2

**Sample Log**

```
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - ORACLE_HOSTNAME=xxxxxxxxxx[OVERRIDES: 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD-MON-YYYY 
HH24:MI:SS [OVERRIDES: DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - xxxxUsername=MDMPIUSER [OVERRIDES: MDMPIUSER]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - BUNDLE_GEMFILE=uri:classloader://installer/Gemfile [OVERRIDES: uri:classloader://installer/Gemfile]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - TIMEOUT=900 [OVERRIDES: 900]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - SHLVL=4 [OVERRIDES: 4]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - HISTSIZE=1000 [OVERRIDES: 1000]
2017-03-03 10:43:18,736 [main] WARN  - JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre [OVERRIDES: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre]
2017-03-03 10:43:20,156 [main] WARN  - APP_PROPS=/home/xxx/conf/appProperties [OVERRIDES: /home/xxx/conf/appProperties]
```

Comment: sample input and output

Comment: Input
Time retrieved from DB
StartTime - 2017-11-02 10:20:00
EndTime -  2017-11-02 11:20:00

The time present in log
T1 - 2017-11-02 10:17:44
T2 - 2017-11-02 11:19:32

Output:
Entire Log text between T1 & T2

Comment: as you can see, comments are not well suited to convey formatting, edit your question instead

Comment: @AkashGujarathi, please edit your question with sample input and expected output in code tags.

Comment: Haven't added the code tags for input and output but it is now formatted and edited in the question itself so it's easy to understand. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @AkashGujarathi: What's the format of your log file ? Paste few lines in your original question.

Comment: @batMan sample log lines are added

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk -v start="$StartTime" -v end="$EndTime" '
function fonct(date)
{
  gsub(/-|,| |:/,"",date)
  return date
}
BEGIN{
  start=fonct(start)
  end=fonct(end)
}
{
  a=fonct($1$2)
  if (a>=start && a<=end)print $0
}' infile
```